# Let $\beta$ be a subset of a discrete metric space (IR, $\rho$). Find the boundary points.

Tags: analysis

Let $β$ be a subset of a discrete metric space $(\mathbb R, ρ)$. Find the boundary points.

In the case of a discrete metric space, we know that $B(x,0.5)={x}$, because every distinct point from $x$ is 1 unit away from it. In this scenario, if I make an open ball around $x$, it is part of $\beta^c$. So, the intersection of open ball and $\beta^c$ is nonempty, right? Therefore, I can say $\{x\}$ is a boundary point of a discrete metric space. Could anyone please confirm if I am on the right track?

Also, the definition of boundary point we have to use is that the intersection of open ball and $\beta^c$ should be nonempty.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question, but in a discrete metric space $X$, there is no boundary point whatsoever. The discrete metric induces the discrete topology in which every subset is open. The boundary of the subset $A$ is defined as
$$\partial A=\overline A\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$$
Since the space $X$ is discrete, $\overline A=A$ and $\overline{X\setminus A}=X\setminus A$, so $$\partial A=\overline A\cap\overline{X\setminus A}=A\cap (X\setminus A)=\emptyset$$
Another equivalent definition is
$\partial A=\overline A\setminus A^\circ$, and again $$\partial A=\overline A\setminus A^\circ=A\setminus A=\emptyset$$

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how in a discrete metric A intersection A complement (X\A) is nonempty